# Programmatically Gathering NUnit results

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I am running some NUnit tests automatically when my nightly build completes.  I have a console application which detects the new build, and then copies the built MSI's to a local folder, and deploys all of my components to a test server.  After that, I have a bunch of tests in NUnit dll's that I run  by executing "nunit-console.exe" using Process/ProcessStartInfo.  My question is, how can programmatically I get the numbers for Total Success/Failed tests?

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider using a continous integration server like CruiseControl.NET?

It builds and runs the tests for you and displays the results in a web page. If you just want a tool, let the `nunit-console.exe` output the results in XML and parse/transform it with an XSLT script like the ones coming from cruise control.

[Here is an example of such an XSL file](http://files.bryantlikes.com/Code/tests.xsl) if you run the transformation on the direct output of `nunit-console.exe` then you will have to adapt the select statements and remove cruisecontrol.

However it sounds like you might be interested in continuous integration.

Comment: The link seems to be dead. Getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar requirement and what we did was to read into the Test Result XML file that is generated by NUnit.

```
XmlDocument testresultxmldoc = new XmlDocument();
testresultxmldoc.Load(this.nunitresultxmlfile);

XmlNode mainresultnode = testresultxmldoc.SelectSingleNode("test-results");
this.MachineName = mainresultnode.SelectSingleNode("environment").Attributes["machine-name"].Value;
int ignoredtests = Convert.ToInt16(mainresultnode.Attributes["ignored"].Value);
int errors = Convert.ToInt16(mainresultnode.Attributes["errors"].Value);
int failures = Convert.ToInt16(mainresultnode.Attributes["failures"].Value);
int totaltests = Convert.ToInt16(mainresultnode.Attributes["total"].Value);
int invalidtests = Convert.ToInt16(mainresultnode.Attributes["invalid"].Value);
int inconclusivetests = Convert.ToInt16(mainresultnode.Attributes["inconclusive"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

We recently had a similar requirement, and wrote a small open source library to combine the results files into one aggregate set of results (as if you had run all of the tests with a single run of nunit-console).

You can find it at https://github.com/15below/NUnitMerger

Answer (score 0):

I'll quote from the [release notes for nunit 2.4.3](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.4.4):

> The console runner now uses **negative return codes for errors** encountered in trying to run the test. Failures or errors in the test themselves give a **positive return code equal to the number of such failures** or errors.

(emphasis mine). The implication here is that, as is usual in bash, a return of 0 indicates success, and non-zero indicates failure or error (as above).

HTH